# Check type with is for multiple generic types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net5

In the code below, how do I change the if statement to also allow `IDomainEntity<string>` inside the block? I've tried a few things (`IDomainEntity<object>`, or add an `||` to the if statement) but each has given me different compile time errors or just not gone inside the if statement.

```
foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    if (changedEntity.Entity is IDomainEntity<int> entity)
    {
        switch (changedEntity.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entity.CreatedBy = user;
                entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                break;
            case EntityState.Modified:
                Entry(entity).Reference(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                entity.UpdatedBy = user;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected result from it? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: It looks like you want a non-generic version of IDomainEntity, since the type parameter is irrelevant for this piece of code

Comment: @JonasHøgh Agreed. Simply extend your `IDomainEntity<T>` from an empty `interface IDomainEntity {}` interface.

Comment: @JonasHøgh @abdusco Yes thanks that works. To clarify for others, I added  `IDomainEntity` interface and gave it all the fields that are not generic. Then I made `IDomainEntity<T>` extend that, and just added the generic field to it. Then in the code in the question I used `IDomainEntity`.

Comment: @abdusco: Not _empty_. That would defeat the purpose. Rather, move all things from `IDomainEntity<T>` that _don't_ rely on `T` into `IDomainEntity` so they can be accessed without needing to specify a generic type that is irrelevant for the use case at hand.

Comment: @Flater, yes, that's a good point

Answer (score 0):

You can define a base IDomain for all your SubDomain interfaces

```
public interface IDomain
{
    bool SpecificFlag { get;  }
}
public interface ISubDomain<T> : IDomain
{

}     

public class Entity1 : ISubDomain<int>
{
    public bool SpecificFlag => true;
}
public class Entity2 : ISubDomain<string>
{
    public bool SpecificFlag => false;
}
```

And you can check the value like this

```
var entities = new List<IDomain>();

        entities.Add(new Entity1());
        entities.Add(new Entity2()); 

        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            if(item is IDomain)
                Console.WriteLine($"Item Falg Value : {item.SpecificFlag}");
        }
```